# How would i put this into a function?

Tags: php

Hi everyone i am new to php . i am having some trouble putting this code into a function can anyone explain or show how to do this? as this code will be used more than once

```
 foreach($_POST as $weather_key => $weather){
     $for_now=is_array($weather) ? $weather : trim($weather));
     if(empty($temporary) && in_array($key,$required_weather_fields)){
        $weather_errors[]=$weather;
        $$weather_key='';
     }elseif(in_array($weather_key,$expected_weather_fields)){
        $$weather_key=$for_now; 
     }
 }
```

Comment: Quick recommendation, try to stay away from dynamic variables like `$$weather_key`. This can make code pretty messy very fast.

Comment: thanks , which convention do you recommend i use?

Comment: Creating variables dynamically should be phased out in favor of creating classes with explicit fields, you could for example create a `Weather` class where each key is a field, which you could document explicitely via code comments. People reading your code will love you for this :)

Comment: What was the problem with just wrapping your code with `function do Something() {...}`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't look like you have any parameters, so you would simply write something like this:

```
function weather_function() {
    foreach($_POST as $weather_key => $weather) {
        $for_now = is_array($weather) ? $weather : trim($weather));
        if(empty($temporary) && in_array($key, $required_weather_fields)) {
            $weather_errors[] = $weather;
            $$weather_key = '';
        } elseif(in_array($weather_key, $expected_weather_fields)) {
            $$weather_key = $for_now; 
        }
    }
}
```

Then when you want to use it:

```
weather_function();
```

Comment: If the OP didn't try this, that would be a really silly question

Comment: @JuanMendes yes i did but the only problem i am having is that this is suppose to show the missing fields.When i put inside function the missing fields are not shown

Comment: @jackmonreo: It would help if you expanded your question to show exactly what it is you are trying to accomplish. As it stands, the question is pretty ambiguous.

Comment: @Knossos i want this to be inside a function so i can reuse it.it basically checks to see is values are set and not empty,if they are they go in missing array. if they not empty then variables get created with the same post name

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
function weather($data, $required_weather_fields, $expected_weather_fields, $temporary) {
 foreach($data as $weather_key => $weather){
     $for_now=is_array($weather) ? $weather : trim($weather));
     if(empty($temporary) && in_array($weather_key,$required_weather_fields)){
        $weather_errors[]=$weather;
        $$weather_key='';
     }elseif(in_array($weather_key,$expected_weather_fields)){
        $$weather_key=$for_now; 
     }
 }

 return array($$weather_key, $weather_errors);
}

list($key, $errors) = weather($_POST);
```

You should inject the $_POST array rather than reference it inside the function.